# Why 3 values are printed in console output for powersOf2(int n) program

Tags: java

Problem is when   n is 4, it prints 1, 2, and 4

```
package Example_16;

public class Example {

public static int powersOf2(int n) {
    if (n < 1) {
        return 0;
    } else if (n == 1) {
        System.out.println(1);
        return 1;
    } else {
        int prev = powersOf2(n / 2);
        int curr = prev * 2;
        System.out.println(curr);
        return curr;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    powersOf2(4);
}

 }
```

i expect the output to be only 4 and not 1 and 2 ,but console out put shows below  which i didn't understand that why 1 and 2 getting printed

```
$javac Example_16/Example.java
$java -Xmx128M -Xms16M Example_16/Example
1
2
4
```

Comment: You are recursively calling the method `int prev = powersOf2(n / 2);`, why _wouldn't_ it print more?

Comment: Using the debugger will make it very clear what happens

Comment: thank you got the answer ,you rock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you first call `powersOf2(4)`, `n == 4`. So you follow the `else` branch inside the function:

```
int prev = powersOf2(n / 2);
int curr = prev * 2;
System.out.println(curr);
return curr;
```

The first thing that happens here is that `powersOf2` is called again, with the argument of 2, then of 1. On this third call, `n == 1` and so 1 is returned and printed, as in the line `System.out.println(1);`.

But once that call returns, you're now in the previous call, where the parameter is 2. So now prev = 1, since it was returned. So `curr` gets set to 2, which is `prev * 2`. You then print and return `curr`. This prints 2. When this returns, it is multiplied by 2 and printed and returned again, for a total of 3 prints.

Comment: Thank you really for detailed explaination,Your statement "powersOf2 is called again, with the argument of 2"  is my confusion that how n is automatically getting changed from 4 to 2?apologies for such a basic question because i am supplying n only as 4

Comment: @Tkinfostrings You are supplying n as 4, that's right. But then you call it with `n / 2`. 4 divided by 2 is 2. Did you write this code yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a recursive program.

On first call to method powersOf2 (from main method) n = 4, it goes to else part of powersOf2 where second call to powersOf2 is made.

On second call to method powersOf2 n =2, it again goes to else part of powersOf2, where third call is made.

On third call to method powersOf2 n = 1, it goes to else if part (n == 1) and print 1 in console.
After that it returns from second call where it prints 2 (in else part) and after that it returns from first call and prints 4 (again in else part).

So you are getting printed 1, 2 and 4.

Comment: Thank you gaurav ,my only doubt is how n is automatically getting changed from 4 to 2 when i am supplying n only as 4?,sorry for such a layman question

Comment: thank you gaurav ,another comment solved above query,thanks a ton